# Mysql table format for store last 30 days Data

Tags: mysql

I want to add this data  :

```
id,prod_name,value,date

1,samsung,340,02-02-2014
2,nokia,390,02-02-2014
3,samsung,340,03-02-2014
4,samsung,440,04-02-2014
```

Main problem is create each  rows for each day records......So any way possible to no need  to create every day record for each product

i want to save last 30 days data.

Comment: Could you explain a little? Do you mean you don't want a row for each day?

Comment: ya..right @eXplicit I don't want  row for each day

Comment: Take the date column out and just update the value column?

Comment: I want t0 store every day value in table

Comment: Ah I get it - you want to only keep 30 days data. I don't really think you can do that without making multiple rows

Comment: @explicit if i do with multiple rows than may be  table size increase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not truncate the data every day for any data that is older than 30 days?

Comment: ya truncate 30 days older data but problem If I have 1,00,000 product  than 1,00,000 x 30 = 30,00,000 rows required for 10,00,00 products

Comment: I don't see any way around that if you need to keep a daily breakdown of the data. 300,000 results isn't that bad, though...